# Colab: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I just found a problem about directory making on Colab.

1. First, I checked the current working directory:

   import os

   !pwd

   > > /content/
2. Then, I created a sub-directory and checked it as follows.

   data_path = '/content/kaggle_original_data_cats_dogs'
   !mkdir data_path
   !ls /content/

   > > adc.json  datalab  data_path  sample_data  sampleSubmission.csv  train.zip

Here, we can see that data_path is the third member of /content/.

3. However, when I tried to change the working directory to data_path, I got:

   os.chdir(data_path)

   > > FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/kaggle_original_data_cats_dogs'

So far...I can't figure out what just happened? Is there anything wrong with the lines above?

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is here

```
!mkdir data_path
```

It should be this instead:

```
!mkdir $data_path
```

Comment: Sorry...cuz I am still a newbie to Python, may I ask why do we need to put a symbol $ before data_path?

Comment: Because the `!` call the shell command. You want to pass `python` variable `data_path` to it. Otherwise it will just make a directory name "data_path".